# How can I import google java checkstyle in Sonar Qube 7.8?

Tags: java, sonarqube, checkstyle

I was trying to add google Java code style from checkstyle. but could not get how to do it.
Is Google code style already covered and analyzed in checkstyle by defualt or we have to enable it. I have already installed CheckStyle on Sonarqube 7.8 Free edition

https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/blob/master/src/main/resources/google_checks.xml

Answer (score 0):

On SonarQube you can install plugins as Administrator. ANd there is a CheckStyle plugin for SonarQube available.

Get the correct Version from [here](https://github.com/checkstyle/sonar-checkstyle) which is compatible with your SonarQube Version

Comment: Checkstyle is already installed, you did not get question rightly.

Comment: Yes, sorry my bad.. I do not know how to configure the checkstyle according to your needs.. My only guess is to load the xml configuration somewhere in the config of the plugin